# MAC address generation

Tags: shell

I have the below issue. 
I have kept a constant MAC prefix:

```
prefix=00:0c:29:51:
```

Then, I will be adding two octets. Like say, 4a:20 and I need this to be randomly generated. So I have:

```
mac=$(awk -v min=1000 -v max=10000 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}' | sed -e 's/.\{2\}/&:/g;s/.$//')
```

And lastly,

```
final_mac=00:0c:29:51:$mac
echo $final_mac
```

However, this sometimes generates a duplicate MAC.

```
80:29
67:51
99:48
87:36
87:36
```

One way to mitigate this would be to loop through this text file to check if the current generated MAC exists. If yes, generate it again and check again.

Any thoughts to overcome this workaround I have? Thanks.

Comment: What text file? It appears out the blue on the penultimate paragraph. Please describe the actual problem.

Comment: So, the issue is with the awk command it generates the last 2 octets for my MAC. But randomly it generates a duplicate instance. So my plan was redirect the output of this awk to a file too. Then loop through the contents of the file and check if the current generated $mac exists in the file. If yes, generate MAC again with awk.

Comment: That's a good plan.

Comment: Are you forced to do it in bash or are there any other solutions good for you?

Answer (score 4):

Why `min=1000` and `max=10000`? There are 65536 possible two-octet values, is there some reason to only use part of them?

In shells that have `$RANDOM` (Bash/ksh93/zsh at least), you do this fully in the shell:

```
printf "00:0c:29:51:%02x:%02x\n" $(( $RANDOM % 256 )) $(( $RANDOM % 256 ))
```

Or, if you want to store the generated addresses in a file, and retry until you get a fresh one, something like this:

```
file=./generated_macs
gen() { 
    printf "00:0c:29:51:%02x:%02x\n" $(( $RANDOM % 256 )) $(( $RANDOM % 256)); 
}
while mac=$(gen); grep -q "$mac" "$file" ; do true ; done    
echo "$mac" >> "$file"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the shell is not bash. It is a ESXi server. 
    echo $0
    -sh

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /dev/urandom to generate it:

```
end=$( for i in $(seq 1 2); do character=$( tr -dc "0-9A-E" < /dev/urandom | head -c 2); printf ":%s" $character; done); echo "00:0c:29:51"$end
```

Comment: welcome to U&L `urandom` would not garantee against dupplicate. I think dupplicate was main concerne of OP.